# Converting MySql Query to SQL Room query in Android - kotlin

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite, android-room

I have just got the below mysql query from the backend.
I have to manage this things locally using Room database in Android.

So, The query from backend is as below :

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(timeStamp ,'%d-%b') AS date, DATE_FORMAT(timeStamp ,'%d') AS dateNumber, 
ROUND(AVG(IF(stateOfCharge IS NULL, 0, stateOfCharge)), 2) AS chargeOverTime, 
ROUND(AVG(IF(temperature IS NULL, 0, temperature)), 2) AS temperature, 
ROUND(AVG(IF(current IS NULL, 0, current)), 2) AS averageChargeDischarge 
from batteryDetails 
where name="VERNE000003"
and timeStamp between "2021-03-11 11:40:29" AND "2021-03-12 23:40:29"
Group by DATE_FORMAT(timeStamp ,"%Y-%m-%d") ORDER BY timeStamp;
```

I have tried to buy converting it as below :

```
@Query("SELECT datetime(timeStamp ,'%d-%b') AS date, " +
        "datetime(timeStamp ,'%d') AS dateNumber, " +
        "ROUND(AVG(if(stateOfCharge IS NULL, 0, stateOfCharge)), 2) AS chargeOverTime, " +
        "ROUND(AVG(if(temperature IS NULL, 0, temperature)), 2) AS temperature, " +
        "ROUND(AVG(if(current IS NULL, 0, current)), 2) AS averageChargeDischarge " +
        "FROM " + DatabaseConstant.mUserBatteryDetailsTable +
        " WHERE name= :batteryId and timeStamp between :startDate AND :endDate " +
        "GROUP BY datetime(timeStamp ,'%Y-%m-%d') ORDER BY timeStamp")
suspend fun getHistoryData(batteryId: String, startDate: String, endDate: String): List<BatteryDetails>?
```

But getting below error:

> error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or
> missing database (no such function: if)
> public abstract java.lang.Object getHistoryData(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()

Comment: Replace IF() with CASE.

Comment: @Akina thanks mam, Now getting : "SQL error or missing database (near ")": syntax error)" pls. guide.

Comment: `IF(A,B,C)` => `CASE WHEN A THEN B ELSE C END`. But in your case `IF(column IS NULL, 0, column)` may be replaced with `COALESCE(column, 0)`.

Comment: The equivalent of `IF(stateOfCharge IS NULL, 0, stateOfCharge)` in any database (except Access) is `COALESCE(stateOfCharge, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Query Solved is as below :

```
 @Query("Select strftime('%d %m',datetime(timeStamp, 'unixepoch')) as dates, " +
        "strftime('%d', datetime(timeStamp, 'unixepoch')) as dateNumber, " +
        "round(avg(coalesce( stateOfCharge,0))) as chargeOverTime, " +
        "ROUND(AVG(coalesce( avgTemperature,0))) as avgTemperature, " +
        "ROUND(AVG(coalesce(current,0))) as averageChargeDischarge " +
        "FROM " + DatabaseConstant.mUserBatteryDetailsTable +
        " WHERE name= :batteryId and timeStamp between :startDate AND :endDate " +
        "Group by datetime(timeStamp ,'%Y-%m-%d') ORDER BY timeStamp")
```